# What was the "precious stone" of Midrash Bereshis 60:6?

Tags: midrash, parashat-chaye-sara, jewelry

In parashas Chayei Sarah (Bereshis 24:22) Eliezer - upon realizing Rivkah is the one of his prayers - gives Rivkah three gifts. One of these gifts is a *"golden nose ring weighing a beka"*. [Midrash Rabbah 60:6](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01633_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2) says:

> Rav Huna in the name of R' Yosef: There was a precious stone in the
> nose ring and it's weight was a beka.
>
> רַב הוּנָא בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יוֹסֵף: **אֶבֶן יְקָרָה** הָיָה בוֹ וְהָיָה מִשְׁקָלָהּ בֶּקַע

What was this precious stone?

Comment: I think it's anybody's guess really. How could we possibly make an answer to this? From the midrash you quoted, it seems Rav Yosef didn't even know what kind of stone it was.

Comment: @ezra Agreed. I was hoping perhaps another credible source would have at least speculated the stone.